# Windows 11 "Oops, you've lost internet" - not recognizing active internet connection. What is it looking for?

Tags: windows-11, internet-connection

I installed a fresh Windows 11, using a virtual machine on my local laptop computer. I received the message "Oops, you've lost internet connection," during OOBE.

I'm aware of certain tools and products that might be blocking the internet connection. Within the virtual machine, I can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a command prompt and I can ping hosts and resolve all DNS names that I tested with no problems. Clearly, the internet connection works but whatever Windows is looking for may be blocked or failing.

**What is Windows looking for to verify that the internet connection is working?**

P.S. I'm aware of how to bypass this. That's not the question.

Comment: What VM connection method are you using? Host Only will block external connections

Comment: @John as mentioned, I have full network connectivity from the command prompt in the virtual machine. The connection is NAT'd.

Comment: Strange then.  I use VMware Pro and multiple guest machines and connections always work. I will continue to think about this.

Comment: @john Thanks, the question is specifically what is Windows 11 looking for to verify if the internet connection is working. I can resolve the underlying issue, I can't find what Windows is doing to determine if the internet connection is working.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to set up as Bridged to get Windows 11 installed and then switch back

Comment: @John after completing the windows install, I can see that it is HTTPS inspection that is probably causing the problem. There is not a valid certificate on the VM guest and websites are coming up with a security warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 falsely reports no internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1777920/windows-10-falsely-reports-no-internet)

Comment: There's lots of questions on this site that reference the Windows connection tests. I've linked one.

Comment: I am trying to find why Windows 11 does this.  I installed a Windows 10 VM in VMware Workstation, set it up, activated it and it runs (as a VM 24x7) . I am wondering why Windows 11 is so different. I assume your host machine has UEFI, Secured Boot and TPM V2 .

Comment: @Appleoddity did you check if you can access the text file under the two URLs I wrote down in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Windows checks two URLs to verify the internet connection:

```
www.msftncsi.com
www.msftconnecttest.com
```

here it tries to access the file `ncsi.txt`. If a connection can be established Windows will recognize the machine to be connected to the internet.